# How to change the value of a XML tag using Perl

Tags: xml, perl

Let us assume that my XML file is like:

```
<? xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
  <Body>
    <RequiredTag>
      #VALUE#
    </RequiredTag>
  </Body>
```

How can I change the value of the required tag using Perl?

E.g.:

```
$XmlHandle->{XML}->{Body}->{RequiredTag} = "RequiredValue";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With XML::Twig::

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => 
                  { RequiredTag => sub { $_->set_text( 'RequiredValue') } },
                pretty_print => 'indented',
              )
         ->parsefile( 'my_file.xml')
         ->print;
```

Comment: 1.  Incase we have more than one "RequiredTag" which is nested under different parent tags.  How can we differentiate ?
2.  And, how to save the xml file after the modification ?

Comment: Have a look at the doc ;--) You can use a more complex expression in the handler trigger, like `Body/RequiredTag`, or `/XML/Body/RequiredTag`; and instead of `print`, you can use `print_to_file( 'updated.xml')`

Comment: print_to_file(FILE) will save the document once i close my Tkx application. Can we save the file dynamically and reload as my Tkx application still running ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean here. print_to_file writes the document to disk as soon as you call the method. If you need the XML for the document, use `sprint`, which returns the XML string for the entire doc.

Comment: I am using GUI application developed in GUI.  I pick a button so that it will write the value into the XML file.  But the modification will taken into effect if and only if i close the application and re-launch it.  With-Out closing the GUI application, the change is not reflected when i try to retrieve the value..  And when i check the documentation, In the doc, "print_to_file ($filename, %options)" %options are not described..

Comment: the docs say : `options: see "flush"`, and `flush` lists the only option as `pretty_print`, so that's not what you are looking for. Beyond that, I can't really help you, I don't know what your code does with the XML. I am pretty sure the file is written when you call `print_to_file` though, you could check that. If the file is used to configure the application itself, then it is possible that you need to restart it, or there may be a way to re-load the config from inside the code. I don't know.